# Prove odd degree polynomials have roots.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity, roots

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial of odd degree. Prove that there is a solution of the equation
$$p(x)=0, x\in\mathbb{R}$$

I am giving this question in an analysis textbook and the only machinery I have to work with is the sequential definition of continuity and the intermediate value theorem. Using only these ideas I am having difficulty coming up with a concrete proof.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to+\infty} p(x) = -\lim_{x\to-\infty} p(x) = \pm\infty$.  So we can pick $x$ sufficiently large that $p(x) < 0$ and $p(-x) > 0$.  Then apply the IVT.

Comment: What I am missing is a concrete proof that those limits are as stated using the sequential definition of convergence or divergence of a function.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $p$ is a polynomial of odd degree, then
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}p(x)=\pm \infty, \quad \lim_{x\to -\infty}p(x)=\mp\infty  $$

Comment: The problem as I have stated it is that I need a concrete proof using sequences. Essentially if given a sequence call it $\{a_n\}$ of real values which diverges to infinity I have to show that $p(a_n)$ diverges as well for any odd degree polynomial.